# View is Getting Change while using *ngIf or *ngSwitchCase in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular

I need a help...

When i am using *ngIf or *ngSwitchCase view is getting changed. Custom javascript function is not working after change. Kindly kelp me to solve this issue.

Comment: You mean the layout is 'broken'? That's normal behaviour as *ngIf will add and remove the element from the DOM, so the layout would be adjusted

Comment: Thanks for your Valuable reply Vege.

Actually the problem is. I used some custom height for tabs and tables using javascript. So when i use *ngIf or *ngSwitchCase, the view is getting adjusted. I am try to keep the fixed height. That is not working..

Comment: Post the actual code or a demo plunker, please

Answer (score 0):

`NgIf` and `NgSwitchCase` are inserting and removing a group of elements from the DOM. If you want to hide them visually but keep the space that they are occupying, do not use them.

Instead, you can toggle [`visibility` CSS property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/visibility).

```
<div [style.visibility]="condition ? 'hidden' : 'visible'"></div>
```

Comment: Hi Lazar, 

In my case it's not working. Right now I used [hidden]. Is there any way like custom style should not affect on property change.

Comment: `[hidden]` is same as `display: none`. The only way to make the element disappear but occupy space as if it were there is `visibility: hidden`.